# Factor weighted values in

Tags: r, summary

In a data frame (`df`) i've got a variable that indicates region (a factor) and other that weights every observation. If I want to know how many observations there is in each region, I just use `summary(df$region)`.

What I'd like to know is how can I see what it would be the size of each region considering the weights of each observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tapply` to sum the weights by region (I think this is what you mean, but please clarify if I misunderstood):

```
> df <- data.frame(region=sample(levels(state.region), 200, rep=T), weight=runif(200))
> summary(df$region)
North Central     Northeast         South          West 
55            46            49            50 
> with(df, tapply(weight, region, sum))
North Central     Northeast         South          West 
27.73835      23.23487      24.71656      26.11786
```

If you actually want some `metric` * `weight`, then you can just modify the `tapply` statement to be `weight` * `metric` instead of just `weight` for the first argument.